# Check hardware support for mobile data Android

Tags: android, telephony

I have an Android issue. My application should be aware if there is a possibility for mobile data connection. Right now I have only found answers about checking if current network IS 3g.

But my function should know if there is a hardware possibility of connecting to mobile network.

So if you take an android device with SIM slot but without SIM card,function should return TRUE

Comment: Do you want to limit installs to those with a mobile connection, or do something different in the app if there is a possibility of a mobile connection?

Comment: No, my application should be aware whether there is possibility for mobile connection and act accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this:

Android Manifest:

Set a [uses-features](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) tag in the manifiest *(this should be used only if one wants to limit his app only for telephony enabled devices)*:

```
<uses-feature name="android.hardware.telephony" required="true"/>
```

Check from the source code:

```
PackageManager mgr = context.getPackageManager();
boolean hasTelephony = mgr.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
```

From the uses-features page, telephony includes:

> The application uses telephony features on the device, such as
>   telephony radio with data communication services.

Comment: Would this return true for tablets that could not make phone calls, but can go to internet via mobile data?

Comment: I find your answer satisfying. I will test everything I can today and if it works I'll accept answer. Cheers!